# API с универсальной формой оплаты с карты/paypal

Tags: javascript, html, css, платежи, paypal

Подскажите, входит ли форма доната с сайта [novayagazeta.eu](https://novayagazeta.eu/articles/2022/06/20/friendrising) в какой-либо готовый API/пакет, которым можно воспользоваться, или же разработчики сайта писали эту форму самостоятельно?

На то что это сторонний софт меня натолкнул тот факт, что аналогичная форма используется на [meduza.io](https://support.meduza.io/).

Если данное конкретное решение не доступно для общего пользования, то интересуют аналоги, позволяющие производить оплату из стран Европы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Достаточно просто открыть инспектор и посмотреть что используется и увидеть что оба сайта работают с https://stripe.com/docs/js

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вопрос полезен только для автора